# Solve a linear system of equations with bounds using LSQR/LSMR SciPy

Tags: python, scipy

Question is quite straight forward. I have an overdetermined system I am attempting to use SciPy LSQR (or LSMR) to solve. However, I cannot find anywhere in the docs on how to set restraints for the minimization.

E.G. Let's say this is the output:

```
The matrix A has 469 rows and 3 columns
damp = 0.00000000000000e+00

atol = 1.00e-06                 conlim = 1.00e+08

btol = 1.00e-06             maxiter =        3

 
   itn      x(1)       norm r    norm Ar  compatible   LS      norm A   cond A
     0  0.00000e+00  1.150e-01  2.291e-02   1.0e+00  1.7e+00
     1  3.33741e-01  9.411e-03  5.359e-05   8.2e-02  2.8e-02  2.0e-01  5.0e+00
     2  2.73042e-01  8.440e-03  3.281e-06   7.3e-02  1.9e-03  2.0e-01  7.8e+01
     3 -1.70218e-01  8.332e-03  3.197e-12   7.2e-02  1.9e-09  2.0e-01  4.1e+02
 
LSMR finished
The least-squares solution is good enough, given atol     
istop =       2    normr = 8.3e-03
    normA = 2.0e-01    normAr = 3.2e-12
itn   =       3    condA = 4.1e+02
    normx = 8.7e-01
     3 -1.70218e-01   8.332e-03  3.197e-12
   7.2e-02  1.9e-09   2.0e-01  4.1e+02
```

We can see the solution arrive to `-0.1`, which is great. However, I'd like to set bounds such that `x(1) >= 0`. Therefore, the iteration would stop when `x(1) = 0.27`. I cannot find anywhere on the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html regarding how to do this.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: *"However, I cannot find anywhere in the docs on how to set restraints for the minimization."* That's because `lsqr` and `lsmr` don't have such options. You might be able to use [`scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html) instead.

Comment: Oh ok, so checking out lsq_linear, it appears there is an option to use lsmr. Do you know why they would even have lsmr separately then? i.e. if I want to run lsmr, just run it through lsq_linear, since it has more options/arguments implemented. Also, additional dumb question, do you know how to partition the output of lsmr? I get a bunch of outputs, but I don't know how partition the count or unbounded solution, or x, etc.

Comment: Cannot edit the above comment, ignore the last part. Found out how to partition the output. (the ```output.x```  where ```output=lsqr()```prints x array) Also, can you put your comment as the answer? The answer may be obvious (i.e. if you can't find it on the wiki, it's because it's not there), but others may have the same question I had.

Comment: I made my comment an answer.  I haven't looked into the history of these functions, and I haven't looked at the code, so I can't help you with the "why..." question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions [`lsqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html) and [`lsmr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html) in `scipy.sparse.linalg` do not have options for adding constraints. You might be able to use [`scipy.optimize.lsq_linear`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html) instead.